# Using Combine to parse phone number String

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm trying to wrap my mind around how Combine works.  I believe I'm doing something wrong when I use the .assign operator to mutate the @Published property I'm operating on.  I've read the documentation on Publishers, Subscribers, and Operators.  But I'm a bit loose on where exactly to create the Publisher if I don't want it to be a function call.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct PhoneNumberField: View {
    
    let title: String
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(title,text: $viewModel.text)
    }
    
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var text: String = ""
        private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
        
        init() {
            $text.map { value -> String in
                    self.formattedNumber(number: value)
            }
            //something wrong here
            .assign(to: \.text, on: self)
            .store(in: &disposables)
            
        }
        
        func formattedNumber(number: String) -> String {
                let cleanPhoneNumber = number.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
                let mask = "+X (XXX) XXX-XXXX"

                var result = ""
                var index = cleanPhoneNumber.startIndex
                for ch in mask where index < cleanPhoneNumber.endIndex {
                    if ch == "X" {
                        result.append(cleanPhoneNumber[index])
                        index = cleanPhoneNumber.index(after: index)
                    } else {
                        result.append(ch)
                    }
                }
                return result
            }
    }
}

struct PhoneNumberParser_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PhoneNumberField(title: "Phone Number")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.receive(on:)`:

```
$text.map { self.formattedNumber(number: $0) }
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] value in
        self?.text = value
    })
    .store(in: &disposables)
```

This will allow you to listen to changes of the `text` variable and update it in the `main` queue. Using `main` queue is necessary if you want to update `@Published` variables read by some `View`.

And to avoid having a retain cycle (`self` -> `disposables` -> `assign` -> `self`) use `sink` with a `weak self`.

Comment: Note that this creates a retain cycle (`self` -> `disposables` -> `Assign` -> `self`) that is never broken, so you will leak memory when the `PhoneNumberField` goes away.

Comment: Absolutely true, thanks. I just focused on the `receive` part and didn't notice the rest :) I updated my answer.